# lxml error when installing mechanicalsoup in Visual Studio for Python 3.11

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, mechanicalsoup

I wanted to practice web scraping with Python module MechanicalSoup, but when I started installing it using `pip install mechanicalsoup` I encountered this error **"Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?"**. I then tried running `pip3 install lxml --use-pep517` to install lxml and its dependencies it returned the same error.
Note that I'm using Visual Studio Code and installing this in a Python Virtual Environment. I looked up every where for possible resolution but so far nothing I found has worked. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does anyone out there have possible solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of researching and hundreds of videos watched, I finally was able to figure this out. As this turned out, I was using Python 3.11, which mechanicalsoup isn't yet fully compatible. I went back a couple of version of Python, 3.96 specifically and was able to install mechanicalsoup in the first attempt.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).